# Converting a half-hourly data into Quarter-hourly data by taking mean of half-hourly values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have half-hourly (30 min interval) Data Table in SQL (SSMS). I want to convert it to Quarter-hourly (15 min interval) by taking mean/average of the preceding and succeeding values.
What SQL query should I run for it?

[image]

Comment: cross apply with 0,1 values and calculate timestamp&value : https://dbfiddle.uk/lxDW1e65

Comment: Sample data as text  would help immensely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using cross apply to convert a single row to a pair of rows

```
select t2.*
from ( 
   select *, dateadd(minute, 15, timestamp) ts2, (value + lead(value) over(order by timestamp))/2.0 v2
   from tbl
) t
cross apply ( 
  values 
    (timestamp, value),
    (ts2, v2)
) t2 (timestamp, value)
where t2.value is not null
order by t2.timestamp
```

Comment: If we wanted to repeat the value for next interval, (i.e. take the previous value and insert it into the quarterly value).  how can we do that?

for example:
Timestamp: 09/09/2021 07:15:00.000
Repeat the Value at 09/09/2021 07:00:00.000

Similarly, 
for timestamp:
Timestamp: 09/09/2021 07:45:00.000
Repeat the Value at Timestamp: 09/09/2021 07:30:00.000

Comment: Just skip v2 calculation and .. `values 
    (timestamp, value),
    (ts2, value)`